# How to retain my date textbox value when reset

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, textbox, reset

I have a textbox that gets the current date and time. I have tried calling the function to get the date but it is not working.

```js
function getDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  var date = td.getDate();
  var month = td.getMonth();
  var mon = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var m = mon[month];
  var year = td.getFullYear();
  var day = td.getDay();
  var da = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  var d = da[day];
  var hour = td.getHours();
  var min = td.getMinutes();
  var datestring = date + " " + m + " " + year + " " + d + " " + hour + ":" + (min <10?'0':'') + min;
  document.getElementById("date").value = datestring;
}
getDate();
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="date">Current date: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="date" readonly size="30" onreset="getDate()"><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: When you set the element's value, also set the *defaultValue*, e.g. `document.getElementById("date").defaultValue = datestring;`. Then when reset, it will adopt the *defaultValue*. No need for a separate event handler. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `getDate` function to button not input.

#### Solution

```js
function getDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  var date = td.getDate();
  var month = td.getMonth();
  var mon = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var m = mon[month];
  var year = td.getFullYear();
  var day = td.getDay();
  var da = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  var d = da[day];
  var hour = td.getHours();
  var min = td.getMinutes();
  var datestring = date + " " + m + " " + year + " " + d + " " + hour + ":" + (min <10?'0':'') + min;
  document.getElementById("date").value = datestring;

  console.log(datestring)
}
getDate();
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="date">Current date: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="date" readonly size="30" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="getDate()" value="get date">
</form>
```

Comment: But now the form doesn't have a reset button. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The function called on the reset event is called before the form gets cleared, so the datestring is set when the function is called but then the form input gets cleared. You will have to do 2 things to make this work

- Move onreset event to the form element
- Add a set timeout so that the input element value is set after the form is reset

```js
function getDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  var date = td.getDate();
  var month = td.getMonth();
  var mon = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var m = mon[month];
  var year = td.getFullYear();
  var day = td.getDay();
  var da = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  var d = da[day];
  var hour = td.getHours();
  var min = td.getMinutes();
  var datestring = date + " " + m + " " + year + " " + d + " " + hour + ":" + (min <10?'0':'') + min;
 
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("date").value = datestring)
  
}
getDate();
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onreset="getDate()">
  <label for="date">Current date: </label>
  <input type="text" id="date" readonly size="30" >
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a form is reset, elements adopt their *defaultValue*. Setting the value **property** does not affect the *defaultValue*, however setting the value **attribute** does.

So either set the element's *value* and *defaultValue*, or just set the *value* attribute instead, e.g.

```js
function getDate() {
  let {year, month, day, weekday, hour, minute} = 
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
      weekday: 'long',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    }).formatToParts(new Date()).reduce(
      (acc, part) => {
        acc[part.type] = part.value;
        return acc;
      }, Object.create(null)
    );
  let datestring = `${day} ${month} ${year} ` +
                   `${weekday} ${hour}:${minute}`;
  // Do this
  document.getElementById("date").setAttribute('value', datestring);

  // Or this
  // document.getElementById("date").value = datestring;
  // document.getElementById("date").defaultValue = datestring;
}

window.onload = getDate;
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input placeholder="Enter something to show form is reset"><br>
  <label for="date">Current date: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="date" readonly size="30"><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

I refactored the date formatting function a little too. :-)